# Ruby Metaprogramming: dynamically define methods based on database entries?

Tags: ruby, database, testing, metaprogramming

I have a model that's dynamically defining some methods based on database content. Something like this:

```
class MyHelperClass
  def self.breeds
    Dogs.pluck(:breed)
  end

  breeds.each do |breed|
    class_eval <<-RUBY, __FILE__, __LINE__+1
      def #{breed}?(val)
        val == "#{breed}"
      end
    RUBY
  end
end
```

Basically, I want to define a 'checker' method for each breed. It seems to work fine, and I have extensive rspec tests which pass locally, but they fail (NoMethodError) on our continuous-integration service (circleci).

I'm populating the test database like so:

```
before(:all) do
  [:labrador, :dalmation, :boxer].each do |breed|
    Dogs.where(category: "large").first_or_create(
      { breed: breed }, without_protection: true
    )
  end
end
```

I'm wondering two things:

1. Why might my tests be failing, despite passing locally
2. If new breeds are added to the Dogs table during runtime, will the corresponding breed-methods be created on the fly, or will that only happen when the server is restarted?

Comment: how are they failing?

Comment: @UriAgassi They get NoMethodError's, like `undefined method 'labrador? ' for #<MyHelperClass:0x000....>`

Comment: where does `labrador` come from? the database or the test? (are you populating the database in the test? if you are, when are you populating it? are you tearing it down at the end of the test?)

Comment: I should've mentioned, I'm populating the test database in a before block (see above edit)

Comment: possibly in your integration system the classes are _autoloaded_ before the rspec starts running (i.e. before the database is populated), so `Dogs.pluck(:breeds)` returns empty array. to check it, add a `puts` inside `before(:all)`, and inside `self.breeds` to see the timing in which they are called.

Comment: Turns out it sometimes fails locally if I run the entire test suite, rather than just this spec file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how your tests are failing, so I can only guess it might have something with the database connection, or maybe the actual database contents, which might be different than on your local machine.

Regarding your second question - the methods are created *only when the code is run*, in your case it is when the class is defined. If the database changes, there is no hook that will synchronize the declared methods (add or remove them).

I would strongly advise *against* implementing it this way, and maybe you should consider making one method which actually checks against the list of current `breeds`, or against a cached copy, which is refreshed once every couple of minutes...

Comment: I think you're right to advise against implementing it this way. Not the best use for metaprogramming, especially as there's only a small number of methods I'd need to hard-code.